# How do I access Kik through Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp

Is it possible to get on the Kik network with Pigdin? I'm told it uses xmpp but I can't figure out the configuration settings.

Answer (score 4):

No, at [one point it was possible](http://tmbl.in/post/2584260025/kik-via-desktop) but no more. There is an [open bug on this issue](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12959) but it's been dead for over a year.

> Yes, Kik uses XMPP, but it seems that they have some strange non-standard stuff in place that will prevent random Jabber clients from signing in. [*source*](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12959#comment:3)

The Pidgin team may add a plugin if someone can reverse engineer that proprietary components of the Kik XMPP protocol, but no luck thus far.